# How to evaluate the quality of custom memory allocator?

Tags: c++, c, testing, memory-management

What characteristics should be checked when evaluating memory allocation?

Performance of allocation and de-allocation? Are simple stress-tests  enough? How to check the quality of allocation?

For example, I found Oracle's test for  [malloc](https://blogs.oracle.com/rweisner/entry/test_harness_for_malloc), but it's only Oracle's view of the problem. And this test is oriented only to multi-threaded performance.

How people usually checks their allocators?

Comment: You'll have to decide what problems you want a custom allocator to solve first.  Do you just want faster memory allocation?  Do you make large numbers of allocations of predictable size?  Are you writing a long running app on a platform with limited memory, meaning that fragmentation is a concern?

Comment: Does it means that allocator should be checked only from one point of view? Only for speed? Only for fragmentation? And etc?

Comment: Sorry, no, I didn't mean to suggest that at all.  Most allocator tests I've seen focus on speed.  If you're writing a linux desktop library, this may be all you care about.  If you're writing something less common, you'll need to decide how many different (often conflicting) use cases matter to you and seek out or design tests accordingly.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just to give more focus on the "how", rather than the "what", whic the other answers seem to deal with. Here's how I would do it.

**First Step - Make it possible to compare approaches**

Determine what qualities you value. Make a list, prioritize and finally, make a value function.

That is, figure out which measurements are the most useful indicators of quality, in your view/case. A few good measurements could be average time to allocate a memory block, total runtime of the application (if applicable), average frame rate, total or average memory consumption ... It all depends on what you wish to achieve.

Then, create a function which, given these measurements from a test run, gives you a value which can be used as quality measure. The simplest case would be to simply decide a weight factor for each of the measurements. These weight factors should embody both the importance of each measurement and, if they use different units (such as nanoseconds for average allocation time and bytes for average memory consumption), attempt to scale them to compare fairly.

**Second Step - Device a test scenario**

This should be as close to a realistic case as possible. The best would be simply the actual code that you want to use your memory allocator for, with added code for taking all the measurements needed to compute your value function.

**Third Step - Test**

Write a bunch of different allocators and test them all against each other, as well as the default or without any allocator (if applicable). Measure all results, compute the value function for each and rank them according to the results. Keep in mind all the different considerations that you always need to think of when performing performance measurements.

**Fourth Step - Evaluate and re-iterate**

Look at how the different solutions stack up against each other. Apply some critical thinking. Do these results actually correspond to how you *experienced* the quality each allocator during the tests? If the results do not match what you thought you saw.

For example, if the one which seemed blazing fast and gave a total runtime of half a minute less than the rest, gets a mediocre score.. Well, then it's time to scrutinize your approach. Perhaps there's a bug in your measuring? Or perhaps you need to re-evaluate your chosen value function... Re-iterate steps one through four until the results are clear and seem in accordance with your actual experience in testing them.

Answer (score 3):

Usually, the performance of a memory allocator is about the speed of the finding and creating a memory chunk in the heap depending of the size of the manipulated memory blocks. And, also (but more recently), how does it behave in the case of multithreaded allocations. You can find interesting studies and benchmarks in the following list:

- [ptmalloc - a multi-thread malloc implementation](http://web.mit.edu/course/13/13.715/build/lam-7.1.3/share/memory/ptmalloc/)
- [Benchmarks of the Lockless Memory Allocator](http://locklessinc.com/benchmarks_allocator.shtml)
- [Dynamic memory allocator implementations in Linux system libraries](http://www.dent.med.uni-muenchen.de/~wmglo/malloc-slides.html)
- [A Scalable Concurrent malloc(3) Implementation for FreeBSD](http://people.freebsd.org/~jasone/jemalloc/bsdcan2006/jemalloc.pdf)
- ... probably many others ...

Answer (score 1):

I guess my answer is not genius but - it depends.

If you are writing custom memory allocator you probably knows what should be it's characteristic. Eg. if you want to have allocator allowing you to quickly allocate a lot of small object and you dont really care about memory usage overhead you should probably have different tests then when you are creating allocator for big objects and you want to save as much of memory as it's possible even with cost of CPU time.

Stress tests are always good because it can help you to find some race conditions and check if your allocator is bugfree, but perfromace test depends on what you wanted to achive.

Answer (score 1):

Here are the metrics that one should consider when optimizing/analyzing the dynamic memory allocation mechanism in the system.

- *Implementation overhead* - how much memory does it cost to keep the allocation's internal data structures operational. Additionally, if these structures grow over time or pre-allocated once (both approaches have pros and cons and both are valid).
- *Operational efficiency* - how long does it take to allocate/free a memory block. Here usually the allocation is a challenge, because it is almost never a constant time and depends on characteristics of previously allocated blocks of memory. Freeing the block looks straightforward but if combined with memory de-fragmentation, deserves further attention (will not be covered here).
- *Thread safety* has less to do with allocation itself and more with the decision to use certain solution in the system. Basically here, if you don't have threads - there is nothing to worry about. If you do have threads - make sure that your allocation will not be interrupted while at work.
- *Memory fragmentation* - actual layout of the allocated memory. Here two completely contradicting requirements come in play - you allocate as soon as you find the right spot in your buffer, or you make sure you cause as little fragmentation as possible. Former is fast, whilst the later is more resource-friendly (and also potentially slower).
- *Garbage collection* - This is a separate topic and a field of study on its own, it is being mentioned only for the sake of completeness. Important is to understand, that even if your don't plan on releasing allocated memory too often, GC can still be of use to help with analysis of already allocated memory, preparing internal data structures for the next efficient memory allocation. IDLE CPU time is arguable the best moment to do this house keeping task. This topic, however is out of scope of this question.